# Unable to access Amazon webs with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ssl, https, amazon-web-services

When going to a secure Amazon page over HTTPS, using either Chrome and MS Edge, the following Error comes up:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

www.amazon.com uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

More Details:

The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite. This is likely to be caused when the server needs RC4, which is no longer considered secure.
```

[image: Screenshot of the error page]

I'm using the latest version of Chrome (50.0.2661.87), and reinstalling it didn't help.

Comment: Works for me using latest chrome build in W7....https://www.amazon.com/

Comment: I am currently on the latest Version of Chrome too. Version 50.0.2661.87 m.

Comment: Weird, never have experienced that error in Chrome, I would try uninstalling then reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Just re-installed chrome. No Luck. IE is also not working, Following error;

"Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://www.amazon.com  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol. Please contact the site administrator."

Note: I did Check to see if  TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 are turned on.

Comment: Does this problem happen also with other https sites or only with amazon? Do you have some firewall/AV software installed on your machine or in the network which does SSL interception?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an extremely dated question, but I found this has often been an issue when using a private VPN like ExpressVPN or some other service.  If you're using a VPN, try shutting it off, or try switching your connection to a different location.

Hope this helps!